# A riddle not for Jewish Women

Tags: riddle

To the British I am short
While the Americans have me long.
The seat I'll save you
Will be very last minute.
That is because I am not very good.
To the bully, I am a laugh,
While those who exercise hard hear me often.

What am I?

Comment: I thought about something naughty... :P

Comment: @You now I can't think of a better answer :D! it just FITS PERFECTLY!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the answer is:

> Pants

Why?
Because:

```
To the British I am short
```

> In the U.K. pants are underwear

```
While the Americans have me long.
```

> While, in the U.S., pants tend to be a normal attire, worn OVER underwear.

```
The seat I'll save you      
Will be very last minute.
```

> To succeed `by the seat of your pants` is by a very thin margin, like at the last minute.

```
That is because I am not very good.
```

> You could say I am pants at it.

```
To the bully, I am a laugh,
```

> A bully tends to laugh, derisively, when they `pants` someone.  (Meaning, to sneak up and quickly pull their pants down.)

```
While those who exercise hard hear me often.
```

> A person, who exercises, pants, once they are out of breath.

**EDIT:** Oh, right.  I forgot to mention.
The title, because:

> A Jewish woman is not allowed to wear pants, because they are considered against her gender.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not so sure about this but then again, I'm not good at riddles. Is it a:

> Cake?

To the British I am short:

> [Shortcake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcake) originates from the UK

While the Americans have me long:

> (Not so sure on this one) Americans tend to (or are stereotyped) as having larger portions of food which includes longer cake.

The seat I'll save you:

> People save a seat for cake. Especially during birthdays, the cake reserves a seat for the one whose birthday it iss

Will be very last minute:

> Cake is a food which is usually served last or as dessert, which can be considered "last-minute"

That is because I am not very good:

> Cake is unhealthy, with all of its sugar and other stuff

To the bully, I am a laugh,

> (Not sure on this one) Too much cake can make you fat, this can lead to bullying

While those who exercise hard hear me often:

> People who exercise trying to loose weight may hear cake in their head, making them desire it.